# Неправильно работает th:classappend

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Я использую Thymeleaf в своем тренировочном проекте. Мне нужно на основе результата условия, добавить/не добавить класс. Я уверен в том, что строка `task.getTaskState()` выводит мне UNFINISHED/FINISHED для каждого задания соответственно. Но почему-то, Thymeleaf мне подставляет класс 'NEDOBRE' для абсолютно каждого задания. Мне кажется, проблема в синтаксисе, но я испробовал все варианты, которые нашел в Интернете. Буду очень благодарен за каждый ответ!

Код HTML:

```
<div class="task" th:each="task : ${tasks}">
                    <div th:classappend="${task.getTaskState() == UNFINISHED} ? btns-done : NEDOBRE" class="btns task-form">
                        <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/admin/tasks/{id}/delete(id=${task.getId()})}">
                            <a class="btn btn-admin" th:href="@{/admin/tasks/{id}/edit(id=${task.getId()})}">Edit</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-admin">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                        <p th:text="${task.getDateString()}"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

P.S. извиняюсь за форматирование текста кода...

Comment: Что такое `UNFINISHED`? Имя Thyemleaf переменной ? Наверное нет. А если это просто литерал то нужны ковычки. Тоже самое нужно сделать для имен классов вы пытаетесь добавить . Это будет работать: `th:classappend="${task.getTaskState() == 'UNFINISHED'} ? 'btns-done' : 'NEDOBRE'"`

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, да, это рабочий вариант, но я забыл упомянуть, что TaskState, это у меня Enum. Ваш вариант оказался правильным, так как я просто к task.getTaskState() прибавил task.getTaskState().toString(), и уже обернул в  кавычки все остальное, следуя Вашим указаниям. Спасибо!

Comment: Здесь все расписано как работать с enum: [Working with Enums in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-enums)